How do I correctly javac my file on Linux?
So, you can think i'm stupid, but i can't javac my file.
I started with java yesterday and tried to make a simple code. I made it, but when i try
"javac HellWorld.java" it gives me this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in 
from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CommandNotFound'
can anyone help me with this?
(i use Linux Mint MATE 21.3)
I tried to get into the directory where my file is and i think i tried most of the solutions in the internet, but nothing helps.
Java -version works and i have installed openJDK.
EDIT:
Sorry everyone, my code was wrong and it said Public Class Main instead of HellWorld.

Which "openJDK" did you install?  My guess is that you installed a JRE package rather than a JDK package; i.e. one that doesn't include the developer tools, such as javac.

Tip: Delete all traces of your install. Then download SDKMAN!, a clever set of shell scripts that makes finding, downloading, installing, and uninstalling a quick, simple, painless act.

Show your  Java code. Show results of your java --version.

You might be suffering satanic troubles after omitting the o in your .java file name.

You said: "Sorry everyone, my code was wrong and it said Public Class Main instead of HellWorld.". Did you solve your problem?

Open a terminal and do sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep -i jdk. What do you get? If nothing, then, since software should be installed with the package manager, you should install the latest jdk with (sudo) apt

Run java -version and javac -version in your terminal. Both commands should return a version number. If javac -version doesn’t return a version number, it means that the JDK (Java Development Kit) might not be properly installed. The JDK includes javac, while the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) does not.
